# DataError: (psycopg2.DataError) invalid input syntax for integer: "https://api.stormpath.com/v1/accounts/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-security

I was using Flask-Stormpath and then I switched to Flask-security instead of Flask-Stormpath. So I uninstall it(stormpath). 
But somehow I don't know it is taking stormpath account to find user detail.

```
DataError: (psycopg2.DataError) invalid input syntax for integer: 
"https://api.stormpath.com/v1/accounts/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
LINE 3: WHERE auth_user.id = 'https://api.stormpath.com/v1/accounts/...

[SQL: 'SELECT auth_user.id AS auth_user_id, auth_user.uuid AS auth_user_uuid, auth_user.created_at AS auth_user_created_at, auth_user.updated_at AS auth_user_updated_at, auth_user.deleted_at AS auth_user_deleted_at, auth_user.email AS auth_user_email, auth_user.password AS auth_user_password, auth_user.first_name AS auth_user_first_name, auth_user.last_name AS auth_user_last_name, auth_user.active AS auth_user_active, auth_user.confirmed_at AS auth_user_confirmed_at, auth_user.last_login_at AS auth_user_last_login_at, auth_user.current_login_at AS auth_user_current_login_at, auth_user.last_login_ip AS auth_user_last_login_ip, auth_user.current_login_ip AS auth_user_current_login_ip, auth_user.login_count AS auth_user_login_count \nFROM auth_user \nWHERE auth_user.id = %(id_1)s \n LIMIT %(param_1)s'] [parameters: {'id_1': u'https://api.stormpath.com/v1/accounts/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 'param_1': 1}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is passing URL where it should pass the id of the user to a function.

Please try to figure out where in your code this is being passed errorneously. If you cannot fix your code please edit the question and include a full traceback and related code.

Comment: Hey I just checked it today and it is working fine! I guess since Flask-stormpath is also using Flask-security it happened due to cache.
Because my local env was working good all time and with the same code production was not working as expected.

Thank you though.. :)